# User's PowerShell Profile Path Location on Linux and macOS?

Tags: linux, macos, powershell, profile

I cannot find the user's PowerShell local profile file on Linux. Where is it located at on non-Windows OSs?

Answer (score 4):

Following the [XDG Base Directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-0.6.html) the user's profile file is located at:

`~/.config/powershell/profile.ps1`

Source: [What's New in PowerShell Core 6.0 - Filesystem](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-core-60?view=powershell-6#filesystem)

Comment: it does not exists by default?

Answer (score 4):

You can always get the profile location on any OS by executing `$PROFILE` at the command prompt. This will output the location of the profile file.

For example, on my Mac

```
> $PROFILE
/Users/robb/.config/powershell/Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1
```

Comment: On a fresh install of pwsh on OS X Ventura, this file doesn't exist; the `.config` dir didn't even exist. You have to create it.

Comment: You may need to create it depending on your OS, how you installed PowerShell and what activities you did in PowerShell before looking for your profile file. This is still the location nonetheless.